# SPLASH SCREEN HIDDEN BY MAXIMIZED FORM

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, splash-screen

I have a Windows Form Application to which I added a splash screen created using the splash screen template. I also added an MDI Parent Form. In my project properties, I chose the splash screen and the MDI Parent as the loading form.

I want the MDI Parent to load Maximized, so I changed the WindowState Property in the list to do just that. Now here is the problem:

If I leave the WindowState set to Normal, the splash screen loads, does its thing, closes, then loads my MDI Parent just like it is supposed to, BUT, if I set the WindowState of the MDI Parent to Maximized, the splash screen displays for about a second, the MDI Parent loads on top of the splash screen, and the splash screen finishes in the background and then closes.

I tried giving Focus back to the splash screen in the Lost Focus event but that didn't work. I know splash screen is still open and working when it gets covered up because I can hit ALT+TAB and see it just before it closes on its own like its supposed to. I also never adjusted any of it's time settings or any other settings.

How do I keep the splash screen on top while my MDI form is Maximized? or how do I delay the MDI until the splash screen has done its job? I dont understand why I am getting this result.

Comment: You must have something else interacting with it.  I tried SDI, MDI, with vshost and Stand Alone, and couldn't duplicate your problem.  Try duplicating the problem with a fresh project, then start doing property changes from your existing project until you've recreated the project or found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Private Sub MDIMainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) 'Splash screen display time
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub
```

For my project it's work.